# How to preserve the original colors of an image after adding text to it using PIL Python?

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library

I am trying to add some text on my image using PIL, see the code below,

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
import sys

image = Image.open('image.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial',40)
draw.text((700, 470),'Text',(0,0,0),font=font)
img.save('out-image.png','PNG')
```

But I lost the original colors of the image, see below images,

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZdvQ.png)

[After adding text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUwEJ.png)

How I can preserve the original colors.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in PIL to me. I think it is because your image is palettised and the `draw.text()` is messing up the palette.

For a work-around, you can convert to an RGB image when you open it to avoid palette issues. Change to this:

```
image = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')
```